# can not create join index in teradata database

Tags: teradata

i want to create a single table join index in teradata database,

here is the code i use:

```html
create join index emp_ji as
sel
employee_number,
department_number,
last_name,
manager_employee_number
from customerservice.employee
primary index(last_name);
```

But i get the following errors:

[image]

I use user DBC, which should have all access,

Comment: As the error message clearly states, you can't create tables in dbc. Simply qualify the name of the join index (`create join index mydb.emp_ji`) or switch your default database (`DATABASE mydb;`) before creating it.

Comment: good, it works now,